# Hibernate and its Cache Vs JDBC and Memcached for Web Analytics Software

Tags: hibernate, orm, jdbc

My lead suggested me to use Hibernate for a web analytics software which retrieves huge amounts of data. I was planning to use JDBC/Spring DBC for the application and cache the data using Memcached or Redis. Caching is important in our Application. So which is better option and what can be tradeoffs?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's agree that there's no such thing as "Hibernate Cache". What exists is an integration on Hibernate to allow the usage of external cache providers (and no, don't consider the cache included in Hibernate as production-ready).

Second, let's also agree that nobody can tell you what's the best solution for you, based on what you described. The way your question is formulated, any answer you'll get is just a matter of personal bias.

With that said, I'd say that you'll be better off with Hibernate. The reason is simple: Hibernate will manage the cache for you. If somebody adds some record, it will automatically invalidate the query caches that might be affected. With plain JDBC (or Spring), you'll have to remember about the cache everywhere, and you'll certainly forget about it from time to time. Besides that, Hibernate can be integrated with a data grid (Hibernate OGM), so, if you later decide that RDBMS is not the right solution for your problem, you just change the persistence provider and you can use a NoSQL database in the backend.